# How to move java project from Netbeans in windows to Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, netbeans

I have made a java project using netbeans in windows. Now I want to run that project on Ubuntu desktop version. I tried installing the environment and tried to run. But not working. 
Any help you can give?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: What you mean not working? Some errors or something? please clarify

Comment: *"Any help you can give?"* - We cannot help unless you provide a better description of your problem.  As it stands, your Question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use version control and thereby transfer and share the code to ubuntu. I successfully sync between windows and ubuntu with several projects and I use code.google.com, bitbucket.org and xp-dev.com. There's also bitbucket and sourceforge. So many version control providers make it possible and advisable for you to use version control to move the code. Using netbeans and for instance svn, you can migrate your project to ubuntu using version control and the plugins for netbeans.

Or, if all you want to do is run your project, you can create a runnable jar file on windows and run it on ubuntu with `java -jar <filename>.jar`.

I hope this helps, or you can clarify your situation for us to get additional help.